# Spatstat: quadrat count test (window is a rectangle, but rotated, off-90 degree)

Tags: r, spatial

When I want to run a quadrat count test in the R package 'spatstat' to test my point process for homogeneity, and my window is a rectangle, but an off-90-degree rectangle, how can I have the quadrats line up with my window? Or will the quadrats always be oriented at 90 degrees? What is an alternate solution to have equal size quadrats distributed across my window?

I am referring to the example line of code:

*>quadrat.test(data, nx=2, ny=3)*

which produces the following plot:
[image: quadrats in spatstat quadrat count test that don't line up with window]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if you provided example data. I will rotate a built in
dataset to use as the input data `X`.

I guess the easiest thing would be to rotate the data and then do your
analysis.

```r
library(spatstat, quietly = TRUE)
#> 
#> spatstat 1.48-0.010       (nickname: 'Present Company Excepted') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
X <- rotate(swedishpines, pi/6)
plot(X, main = "Original data")
```

[image]

```r
e <- edges(Window(X)) # Edges of the window
a <- angles.psp(e) # Angles of the edges (pi/6 ~ 0.5235988)
a
#> [1] 0.5235988 2.0943951 0.5235988 2.0943951

Xrot <- rotate(X, -a[1]) # X rotated back by the first angle
plot(Xrot, main = "Rotated data")
```

[image]

```r
plot(quadrat.test(Xrot, nx = 2, ny = 3))
```

[image]

If for display purposes you need the rotated version you can do:

```r
Xrot_tess <- quadrats(Window(Xrot), nx = 2, ny = 3)
X_tess <- rotate(Xrot_tess, a[1])
plot(X_tess)
```

[image]

```r
plot(quadrat.test(X, tess = X_tess))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Ege Rubak. This is extremely helpful. Next time I will provide sample data (still figuring out how to use this site, and now also realizing that I should have posted on R-help or stack overflow - thanks for your patience). Much appreciated.